# Importing data into Galaxybase using galaxybase-load

Tags: graph-databases

When importing data into Galaxybase using the import tool galaxybase-load, where should the data source file to be imported be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files to be imported should be placed in a subfolder of the "data" directory of the current graph service mount directory, which is the path specified by `--home` when installing Galaxybase